# In windows powershell ISE, trying to bulk update people information. I get this error message

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to bulk update people information. I get this error message.

The users2.csv file contains this:

> UserPrincipalName,Company,CountryOrRegion,DisplayName,Fax,FirstName,Initials,LastName,MobilePhone,Phone,Title,WindowsEmailAddress,Name
>
> test@bio-dynamics.be,Bio-Dynamics,Belgium,Test,Test,Test,Test,Test,Test,Test,Test,test@bio-dynamics.be,Test
>
> test2@bio-dynamics.be,Bio-Dynamics,France,Test2,Test2,Test2,Test2,Test2,Test2,Test2,Test2,test2@bio-dynamics.be,Test2

The error message is this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Csv "c:\scripts\users2.csv" | ForEach {Set-user UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -Company $_.company -CountryOrRegion $_.CountryOrRegion -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -Fax $_.Fax -FirstName $_.FirstName -Initials $_.Initials -LastName $_.LastName -MobilePhone $_.MobilePhone -Phone $_.Phone -Title $_.Title -WindowsEmailAddress $_.WindowsEmailAddress -Name $_.Name}
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'test@bio-dynamics.be'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-User], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Set-User
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
 
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'test2@bio-dynamics.be'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-User], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Set-User
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Can anybody help point me toward the problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you just missing the - before UserPrincipalName?  I haven't tested on my end.

Comment: To overcome typing errors like that, make the code more readable/maintainable by using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on cmdlets with lots of parameters.

Comment: @dno tested, that's not it. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Theo I had never heard about splatting. I read up on it with the link provided. But do you really think this is what's causing the issue?

Comment: @Dries No, the error comes from the fact that you didn't put a hyphen in front of parameter UserPrincipalName. Splatting is a neat way of combining parameters in a Hashtable and use that hash to feed all parameters in one go to the cmdlet. Because it makes code readable, typos like forgetting a hyphen can be a thing of the past.